# Relation between components of tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer

Tags: python, tornado

Taking the following code into account:

```
http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app) 
http_server.bind(options.port)
http_server.start(5)
```

What is the relation between the five subprocesses?? Does the dabatase connection instance start up along with the application share as part of the subprocesses?

What is the best practice to use http_server.start(5)?

Great thanks.

Comment: You don't have any items in there regarding a Database connection. More information is needed in order to properly respond to that point.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you connect to the DB. The simplest method is to use one shared DB connection, which is a class object on `Application` or on a `RequestHandler`. In that case, the single connection instance will be shared among all server processes.

For an example implementation, see the [Blog demo app](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/demos/blog/blog.py).